# Access violation on WakeAllConditionVariable in DLL shutdown

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, winapi

I have a situation where I have a worker thread in a DLL (node native module) that uses a `std::condition_variable` for synchronization. When the executable exits it simply kills my worker threads, and since it's a node native module I have no access to the DLLMain, so I don't know about the impending shutdown.

When I try to notify my (killed and therefore non-existing) thread to shut down with notify_all(), the call simply hangs (on Window 7) or crashes (Windows 10).

After some research I found that the RTL is using a CONDITION_VARIABLE internally. I can reproduce the crash with this little code snippet:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <thread>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <chrono>

std::mutex mutex;
std::condition_variable cond;

CONDITION_VARIABLE win_cond = CONDITION_VARIABLE_INIT;
CRITICAL_SECTION cs;

void worker() {
    //std::unique_lock<decltype(mutex)> lock(mutex);
    //cond.wait(lock);

    EnterCriticalSection(&cs);
    SleepConditionVariableCS(&win_cond, &cs, INFINITE);
    LeaveCriticalSection(&cs);
}

int main()
{
    InitializeCriticalSection(&cs);
    std::thread thread(worker);
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));

    // Simulate DLL shutdown with lpReserved != null
    ::TerminateThread(thread.native_handle(), 0);

    //cond.notify_all();
    WakeAllConditionVariable(&win_cond);  // crash

    thread.join();
    return 0;
}
```

My questions are:

- Is it me or is it a bug?
- What can I do to fix this / work around?

Note that I would like to continue to use the c++ standard libraries as this code has to run on other OSes then Windows.

Comment: *cs* variable allocate wait block on thread stack and push it to *cs*. so *cs* structure have pointer to wait block, which in thread stack. when you kill thread - it stack de-allocated. when you call `WakeAllConditionVariable` code try access wait block in already died thread stack. here and exactly access violation. the terminate thread is always error

Comment: anyway when dll entry point called with `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH` - all another threads already killed. so no sense call `WakeAllConditionVariable` on `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH`

Comment: *"When the executable exits it simply kills my worker threads"* - This is probably the bug. If you want a clean shutdown, make sure all threads have a chance to exit. Someone is calling `TerminateThread`, but [there are no valid reasons to call `TerminateThread`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150814-00/?p=91811).

Comment: @IInspectable - nobody call `TerminateThread`. application kill `ExitProcess`. this api first call all threads in process except current (via `NtTerminateProcess(0, exitcode)`) and then begin call dlls entry points with `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH`. solution - never call `WakeAllConditionVariable` and other synchronization (with another in process threads) - no more threads in process

Comment: @IInspectable @RbMm Unfortunately I can't have a `DllMain` as this is a [node native module](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html), so I can't differentiate between a shutdown or a normal cleanup. This happens in my destructor.

Comment: @Fozi - so you dont know when your destructor called ?

Comment: @RbMm Well, I don't know if it's during a "normal" cleanup, shutdown or process exit. If I had a DllMain I could set a global flag or something and not bother with exiting the thread.

Comment: not clear under which conditions your code called and what it control. are you create worked thread yourself ? thread killed via explicit `TerminateThread` ot simply `ExitProcess` called (this call also kill all threads except current but not free thread stack, unlike `TerminateThread`)

Comment: `CONDITION_VARIABLE` this is single `PVOID Ptr` which is pointer to linked list threads (which call `SleepConditionVariableCS`) wait blocks (allocated from thread stack). if `TerminateThread+CloseHandle` called for thread, while it wait block inserted to `Ptr` - it make all conditional variable structure invalid. and `WakeAllConditionVariable` (which walk by this list) must crash. but `ExitProcess` despite kill threads too, not free it stack. need more information - how , under which condition your code destructor is called. your example not show this key point

Comment: @RbMm Not sure where you are heading - try my example, and you will see it crash. When my destructor is called all threads of that process are gone except for the main thread that calls the destructor. My instance holds a `thread`, a `mutex` and a `condition_variable` and it tries to signal the worker thread to exit. I could choose to not bother stopping my thread, but then other instances, which might be destroyed before the shutdown, will leak `std::thread`s, which is Bad(tm).

Comment: @Fozi - you example and must crash. this obvious. but this is not your actual code

Comment: *When my destructor is called all threads of that process are gone except for the main thread that calls the destructor.* - your destructor called from some dll entry point on `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH` ?

Comment: @RbMm It's a static member of a [wrapped object](https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html#addons_wrapping_c_objects), so it's destroyed like a global. But it is also used as a non-static member by other classes.

Comment: but this member in some *dll* declared or *exe* ? exe destructors called *before* `ExitProcess` called (and another threads can still run), *dll* destructors called after `ExitProcess` called when already only single thread in process. based on your description look like it from dll called. of course we can detect that we last thread (by using ` ThreadAmILastThread` in process, and not call wake function in this case..

Comment: @RbMm As I wrote in the question, it's in a DLL. `ThreadAmILastThread` looks interesting, but I'm trying to stick to the standard library and for sure I have to stick to public APIs.

Comment: `BOOL bLast; ZwQueryInformationThread(0, ThreadAmILastThread, &bLast, sizeof(Last), 0);` - if you got `bLast==true` no more threads in process and no sense call wake